# Xceed CheckComboBox not properly showing selected values from items hardcoded in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, xceed

I try to use a [CheckComboBox](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/CheckComboBox/a7baf42b0ce84afe686ce790e9909af51838dcaa) control from the [Xceed](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit) library.

When I select an item, the control displays `system.windows.controls.comboxitem:"value"` instead of just `value`

Is there a way to display only the value of the selected item without its type?

```
<xctk:CheckComboBox>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="SA" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="NA" />      
</xctk:CheckComboBox>
```

Comment: Can you show the code you use to display the selected item.

Comment: I actually don't have code for that. I use a code to take the chosen items to a list, and than use this list. I need to code it, or it is possible on the XAML file?

Comment: `on the frame I will get written the item I selected. What now written is the entire type- "system.windows.controls.comboxitem:"value""` - there isn't a frame in the provided XAML. Most probably there is some issue with the `Binding` on that frame. If you provide the XAML for that frame(perhaps even a backing model if there is one), then someone may be able to help you. Basically  [mcve]. Though most probably https://stackoverflow.com/questions/840407/wpf-binding-to-combobox-selecteditem will help on its own.

Comment: May be frame wasn't the good word to choose(I am not a native English speaker). By frame I meant to the item that you press on to see the list of the CheckCombobox. I want it to be as tit is on this example- https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/CheckComboBox.                            What you choose is written.

Comment: @AlonH If you are not sure which word to use (and quite often even if you are sure) it may be better to use [a picture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_picture_is_worth_a_thousand_words). Also when you ask a question it is often a good idea to leave only the minimal code necessary to demonstrate the issue (so no unnecessary repetition, irrelevan GUI tinkering like setting of margins) - short concise code samples are much less likely to inadvertently look like some code dump question, thus much more likely to receive an answer. Obviously, sometimes even a minimal sample can be a bit large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular case it can be solved by adding the `DisplayMemberPath="Content"`

```
<xctk:CheckComboBox DisplayMemberPath="Content">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="SA"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="NA"/>
</xctk:CheckComboBox>
```

But whether it is a **designed feature or just a serendipitous behaviour**, I am not sure.

So overall it would be better in the future to read on [WPF binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-Us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-binding-wpf), and use datasources and bindings to make the code similar to what is on the [documentation page](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/CheckComboBox/a7baf42b0ce84afe686ce790e9909af51838dcaa).

```
<xctk:CheckComboBox  
    DisplayMemberPath="Color"
    ValueMemberPath="Level"
    SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedValue}"
    SelectedItems="{Binding SelectedItems}" />
```